# how to change the property of the first form while using a second form?

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I'm using two forms and I disable the first one when the second form shows up. I couldn't find a way to enable the first form when the second one is closed.
Passing a parameter could be a solution but I bet there is a simpler way.
First I thought of enabling the first form on the destructor of the second but could not do it.
Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Why not just open the second form as modal? That will automatically handle suspending execution of the first form while the second one is open.

Comment: Please run a search on StackOverflow, this question has come up *a lot.* Your second form needs a reference to the first form, on which it can either call a method or change a property.

Comment: @codesparkle you are right, there are many topics on this. looks like creating custom events and delegates are the right track.

Comment: @codesparkle You don't *need* to pass a reference to the first form.  In fact, it's not even considered the best approach.  The accepted practice here is to use events.

Comment: @Servy indeed, that would probably be the cleanest way to do it. @Bora you may not need to create a delegate; check out [`EventHandler<TEventArgs>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx) or the various versions of [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action).

Comment: @codesparkle In this case you won't be creating an event at all, just using the existing events that `Form` implements, which means you will be using an already defined delegate, not creating one.  If you needed to add your own event, rather than use one that has already been created, you can use one of those delegates, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show second form with ShowDialog() - form will be shown as modal, first form will be enabled only when second will be closed.

For future problems you can have a field in second form to have instance of first one, and use that instance, if you need, for example you can use custom constructor:

```
class SecondForm: Form
{
   FirstForm _parentForm;

   public SeconForm(FirstForm form)
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      _parentForm = form;
   }

   void DoSomethingWithParent()
   {
      _parentForm.DoSomesting();
   }
}
```

Comment: It worked as I expected. This solves my answer, but still looking for an answer for future similar problems!

Answer (score 2):

As has been mentioned, in this specific case it probably makes sense to use a modal dialog for opening the second form.

To cover the case when that isn't applicable, the accepted best practice would be to subscribe to the `FormClosing` event of the second form from the first, and in the event handler you could enable "yourself" and do anything else that you might want to do as a result of the other form being closed.  Here is a simple example:

```
public partial class ParentForm : Form
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChildForm child = new ChildForm();

        child.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(child_FormClosing);
        Hide();
        child.Show();
    }

    private void child_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: `child.FormClosing += child_FormClosing;` would suffice if you are using an up-to-date version of .NET

Comment: @codesparkle Yes, it would, but VS code completion generates this code automatically, so it's actually more work to change it to that sorter version.  If I was typing this all out in notepad without code completion there are actually several additional changes I would make.  (I'd use a lambda rather than a new method, for example.)